# Check Dialog is open or not in MFC VC ++

Tags: mfc

I have an application (Manager) used to send commands to another application (Instructor) through sockets. From the first application I will have configure some data which is useful to invoke and run the second application. Same time im getting reports from the second application to first application.

Let me explain my question, I have the set of exercises which has to be run in second application. Either I can invoke it from First app or from the second app by invoking the exercise dialog. Once I invoked, I can get the report. For that I have one button in my first app.

Here whats happening,before the exercise dialog get invoked,when i press this button, it shows error.

So, I just want to know whether that dialog is opened or not.

I use GetSafeHwnd(), but once the object created for that dialog class, these handle get some value even the dialog is not open.

Here I pasted the code, once I get the button press 'GenXL' command from first app.

```
  extern CPerfScore *oPerfScore;
    void CMainFrame::ProcessPendingRead(void)
    {
        int nRead;
        CString strBuf;
        CString sCmd;       
        nRead = m_pCltSocket->Receive( &m_pRecPacket, sizeof(Packet));      
        if(nRead > 0)
        {   
                // read the message
                sCmd = m_pRecPacket.sMessage; 
                AfxMessageBox(sCmd);
                if (sCmd.CompareNoCase("CLOSE") == 0)
                {               
                    OnClose();
                }               
                if (sCmd.CompareNoCase("GENXL") == 0)
                {                   
                    if(oPerfScore->GetSafeHwnd() == 0)
                    {
                        oPerfScore->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, IDC_GENERATE_EXCEL);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AfxMessageBox("Exercise dialog not open");
                    }
                }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Re: `it shows error` - what error?

Comment: `if(oPerfScore->GetSafeHwnd() == 0) oPerfScore->SendMessage(...)` This doesn't make any sense. Maybe you mean `if(oPerfScore->GetSafeHwnd()) oPerfScore->SendMessage(...)`

Comment: Some times it hangs ,some times it shows assertion error in first line in the function definition of   IDC_GENERATE_EXCEL, i call SetTimer(), it assertion error on SetTimer function.If i comment that,assertion error in second line.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the assertion dialog? It tells you **exactly** which condition your code violated.

Answer (score 3):

A handle will be valid even if the window isn't currently being shown, as long as it has been created. I think you're looking for the API call IsWindowVisible(). I believe MFC wraps this as a member.

Comment: I am sure you can send `WM_COMMAND` messages to invisible window. I suspect the issue is elsewhere.